# Unity locked in an infinite loop

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just updated my Unity pro to latest version (5.4.0f3) and now I have the editor entering an infinite loop at a specific time in my game.
It looks like it loops inside Unity code in `SceneTracker::FlushDirty` (I selected the instruction looping)

[image: list of instructions repeated]

[image: Call Stack]

I have no idea what could cause this, I hoped someone here would have the same problem + a solution.

Comment: Are you suing any plugins or Editor extension? If so, list them?

Comment: ^ **suing..** I sued a plugin once. I lost it :/

Comment: No plugin, only the UnityVS to work with VS instead of Mono.

Comment: @UmairM lol that's what happens why you type fast. @ Christ I can't tell what's wrong with your Unity. Why not try an empty project and see if that happens too. If it works then you can load your old project and enable/disable scripts one by one until you find the problem. Without seeing your project, it is hard to tell what's causing this.

Comment: I tested several projects, it does that only on this one. Disabling scripts here is not a solution, it's not a trivial project, it has hundreds of script files.

Comment: @ChrisR. I would suggest you to go through all editor scripts try deleting them one by one. There might be something causing the loop. And don't forget to save a backup before that

Comment: There is no editor scripts only gameplay ones. Maybe my best move is just roll back to last working version of Unity but I'm not sure I'll be able to reopen my files as there was a change of files format...

Comment: are you sure you dont have any editor folder in your project? seems impossible to me for a **not a trivial project**

Comment: @UmairM Yes, I'm sure. I understand it can seem odd, but it's because almost nothing is edited inside Unity Editor.